# Convert date stored as Decimal (9, 0) and subtract a year from the date

Tags: sql, date, casting, decimal, datediff

I am trying to convert a SQL date which is stored as a Decimal (9,0) to a date field so I can then use datediff to subtract a year.

I have tried several ways. So far I have been able to cast to a date, but I can't get Datediff to work with this. Can anyone help please?

Here is what I have which converts to a date field:  `Format(cast(cast([DOCDATE] as varchar(10)) as date), 'dd/MM/yyyy')`

When I try using datediff with this `DateDiff(year, -1, (Format(cast(cast([DOCDATE] as varchar(10)) as date), 'dd/MM/yyyy')))` - it results in error: *The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.*

I have tried a variety of combinations of Convert and Cast, but I'm failing each time.

I would really appreciate some help if someone can show me how to do this.

Comment: Do you have some example values of this `decimal(9,0)` and the dates they are meant to correspond to? Believe it or not there's not a *single well-defined standard* for converting between 9 digit numbers and dates.

Comment: Format() doesn't return a date but a varchar, so you can't use that in a calculation. I suppose you can just remove that function as you already convert to a date in the previous call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't quite using the right functions. I'm not sure how your data looks, but this working example might help you fix your problem.

Return the date minus a year as a *date*:

```
select dateadd(year, -1, cast(cast(20220822 as varchar(10)) as date))
```

Return the date minus a year as a *varchar that looks like a date*:

```
select format(dateadd(year, -1, cast(cast(20220822 as varchar(10)) as date)), 'dd/MM/yyyy')
```

Comment: Thanks all for posting. The data is formatted as 20201026 in a decimal (9,0) column. Thank you to @VvdL - this worked perfectly:  select dateadd(year, -1, cast(cast(20220822 as varchar(10)) as date)). Phew! Many thanks.

Comment: Glad it worked, please mark it as the answer so people can find it in the future.